# Work only when popup is opened

Tags: javascript, html

I want this to work:

```
 document.addEventListener("keyup", function (e) {
  var key = e.which || e.keyCode;
  switch (key) {
    //enter
    case 13:
      document.getElementById("messagebtn").click();
      break;
      //space
    case 32:
      document.getElementById("messagebtn").click();
      break;
      //escape
    case 27:
      document.getElementById("messagebtn").click();
      break;

  }
});
```

Only when my pop up alert comes up:

```
<a href='#' onclick='message()'>
  <img id="english" src="images/english.png">
</a>

<div id="message" class="msg" onclick="location.href = 'index-eng'">
  <div>
    <p id="messagetext">English is set to the default language.</p>
    <a href='index-eng' onclick='message()' id="messagebtn">OK</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Because now it shows the popup when I press one of these cases.

Does someone know how that works?

Comment: Code Review note: Don't Repeat Yourself.

Comment: Either disable the event handler when the popup is not displaying, or check if the popup is displaying. What's the problem?

Comment: Use a snippet instead of pasting the code.

Comment: @user202729 Whats the problem? That if i press down the case key the popup turn on. It needs to be enabled only when the popup is there, for the popup to go to the next page when using cases

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of different ways you can implement this behaviour.

**Option 1:**

Create a simple flag, set by default to `false`, and turn it to `true` inside the function that shows your popup. Then, you can use this flag inside your event handler to control the flow based on whether the popup is shown:

```
var popupShown = false;

function message () {
  // ...
  popupShown = true;
}

document.addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
  if (popupShown) {
    var key = e.which || e.keyCode;
    switch (key) {
      //enter
      case 13:
        document.getElementById("messagebtn").click();
        break;
        //space
      case 32:
        document.getElementById("messagebtn").click();
        break;
        //escape
      case 27:
        document.getElementById("messagebtn").click();
        break;

    }
  }
});
```

**Option 2:**

As an alternative, you can add the event listener for `keyup` when you show your popup and remove it when the popup is closed:

```
function showPopup () {
  document.addEventListener("keyup", keyupEventListener);
}

function hidePopup () {
  document.removeEventListener("keyup", keyupEventListener);
}

function keyupEventListener (e) {
  var key = e.which || e.keyCode;
  switch (key) {
    //enter
    case 13:
      document.getElementById("messagebtn").click();
      break;
      //space
    case 32:
      document.getElementById("messagebtn").click();
      break;
      //escape
    case 27:
      document.getElementById("messagebtn").click();
      break;

  }
}
```